# Access main class from UICollectionViewCell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 3 classes.

1. I implemented a `UICollectionView` programmatically -
   `collectionViewClass.m`.
2. The configuration for the `cells` of the `collectionView` - `myCells.m`
3. I have a class `myClass.m` that calls `UICollectionView`.

There is a `label` in `myClass.h` that I want to access in `myCells.m` How can I do that?

I tried:

```
myClass *mainClass = [[myClass alloc] init];
mainClass.myLabel.text = @"Something";
```

But that creates a new instance of `myClass`. How can I access the same `myClass` from `myCells`?

**Update**

`myCells.h`

```
@protocol myCellsDelegate

- (void)changeLabelName;

@end

@interface myCells : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<myCellsDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

`myCells.m`

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    [self.delegate changeLabelName];
}
```

`myClass.h`

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <myCellsDelegate>
```

`myClass.m`

```
- (void)changeLabelName {
    NSLog(@"Something");
}
```

Why doesn't the `NSLog` run?

**Update 2**

Here is where I initialize the `cell`:

```
- (UICollectionView *)datesCollectionView
{
    if (!_datesCollectionView) {
        ...
        _datesCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];
        [_datesCollectionView registerClass:[myCells class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kDIDatepickerCellIndentifier];
        _datesCollectionView.dataSource = self;
        _datesCollectionView.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:_datesCollectionView];
    }
    return _datesCollectionView;
}
```

Comment: You should not try to access myClass from your cell; the cell should not know anything about myClass. What is it you're trying to accomplish? Also, what do you mean by myClass "calls" UICollectionView?

Comment: There is a view in `myClass` that contains the `collectionView`. I probably said it wrong in the question.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do: There is a setter method (which sets the label in the cell) that gets called every time a new cell is created. In that method, I want to check if the text equals a string. If it does, I want to change the label in `myClass.m`.

Comment: You need to show the code for your collection view.

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/noxt/DIDatepicker I got a library from github. The setter method I'm talking about is in the class called `DIDatepickerDateView.m` and in the method of `- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date`

Comment: @rdelmar I should have given the link to the actual files: https://github.com/noxt/DIDatepicker/tree/master/Sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your code. First, I went into the storyboard and set the "tag" property of the Label to "11" (It can be any number you want as long as nothing else is using that number for a tag).

Then in your `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

I put this code:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel = (UILabel*)[collectionView viewWithTag:11];
//check myLabel.text against whatever you want
```

So that the final method looks like the following, which you can add your own "isEqual or isEqualToString" checks:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DIDatepickerCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kDIDatepickerCellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    myLabel = (UILabel*)[collectionView viewWithTag:11];
    //check myLabel.text against whatever you want
    cell.date = [self.dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    cell.itemSelectionColor = _selectedDateBottomLineColor;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! The label is in `myClass`'s class, not in the collectionView. So when I tried [collectionView viewWithTag:11], that didn't work. I then tried [myClass viewWithTag, But I got an error: No known class method for selector 'viewWithTag'

Comment: Which class are you referring to? is it the DIDatePicker or what?

Comment: myClass is the viewController/class I call DIDatePicker. So in the example of DIDatepicker, myClass is equivalent to DIViewController: https://github.com/noxt/DIDatepicker/blob/master/DIDatepicker/DIViewController.m

Comment: Ok try this, I added this to `viewDidLoad` at the end.

`    DIDatepicker *picker = _datepicker;
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[picker viewWithTag:11];
    if ([label isEqual:@"Something"]) {
        // do stuff
    }
`

It's kind of hard to read in a comment, but just imagine a newline after each ";"

Comment: What you are doing is grabbing a reference to the class, not creating one. Then accessing properties of said class. I hope this is what you are trying to do. Whether it's exactly it or not, this is the road you need to go down. Using views and tags and references to classes that already exist.

Comment: I added that to `DIViewController.m` in viewDidLoad, and the problem with doing that is, it doesn't update every time a new cell is created.

Comment: add `_selectedDateLabel = label;` right before the "if statement", then move the if statement to the `- (void)updateSelectedDate` method. Change the if statement to read instead of `if label...` to `if [(self.selectedDateLabel.text isEqual:@"toWhatever"]) {
// do something
}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't call myClass from your cells. A cell should just present your content. Instead you should use the [delegation pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Your cell can hold a reference to an object which implements a certain protocol that you define. You communicate and perform the functionality that you need through this delegate.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Eric you probably already know how to use delegates, even take a look at Apple's UICollectionViewDelegate for example. Also, a quick search for "iOS delegate example" would provide you with many tutorials to get you started.

Comment: instead of "myCellsDelegate" you should use the "UICollectionViewDelegate".
Then, when you init the collectionView, you just set the delegate by `collectionView.delegate  = self`.

You don't need to create a delegate, you just need to use the existing one for the collection view:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/

Comment: @Erakk So should I remove the protocol? And should I set the `collectionView` or the `collectionViewCell` 's delegate to self? (`myMehtod` is in the `collectionViewCell` class.

Comment: @Eric when you initialize your cells (myCells) set their delegate property to your myClass instance.

Comment: @Artal I initialized `myCell` in `collectionViewClass.m`. (Not sure if it makes a difference). And in `myClass`, I didn't initialize `collectionViewClass`, I added `collectionViewClass` as a class in the storyboard. How/Where do I set the delegate to `myClass`?

Comment: @Eric not sure I completely understand. If you're creating custom cells programmatically, you should be able to set the delegate in cellForItemAtIndexPath. If myClass is not available there to be set as a delegate, you can create another delegate and propagate the call. You can also consider using notifications if you just want to notify about a certain change.

Comment: @Artal If I do it in `cellForItemAtIndexpath`, how should I access `myClass`? Should I do `mClass *mc = [[myClass alloc] init];`?

Comment: @Eric if you create a new instance you'll end up with the original issue. If I understand correctly you want to set a specific instance of myClass as the delegate. If myClass is not available at this point (I didn't understand exactly where is it in your hierarchy) you can either use another delegate to get the message to where your myClass instance is found, or (as I said on my previous comment) you can look into other solutions like notifications, but you'll need to do some research to see if it fits your purposes.

Comment: `myClass` is where everything is established. Meaning, `myClass` is a class of a `viewController` in which the collectionView is called.

Comment: @Eric in that case, if myClass is the one containing your UICollectionView, it will be a bit more complicated. You'll can use the same delegate as a property in your collection-view and call the same method, passing the call to the parent which also contains myClass.